# How I use AutoMapper for master detail class

Tags: c#, automapper, master-detail

I'm tring to map the ParentChild Object, but the Child failed to map.
I already configure the automapper to recognize the master and detail class.

here my class and classDTO

```
public class Master {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string masterInfo {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Detail> details { get; } = new Collection<Detail>();
}

public class Detail {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int masterId {get;set;}
    public Master master {get;set;} 
    public string detailInfo {get;set;}
}

public class MasterDTO {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string masterInfo {get;set;}
    public ICollection<DetailDTO> details { get; } = new Collection<DetailDTO>();
}

public class DetailDTO {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int masterId {get;set;}
    public MasterDTO master {get;set;} 
    public string detailInfo {get;set;}
}
```

And here is my main program :

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<Master, MasterDTO>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Detail, DetailDTO>();
                });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var original1 = new Master { id=1,masterInfo="xxxx", 
        details = { new Detail {id = 11, masterId = 1, detailInfo="aaaa"}, 
                    new Detail {id = 12, masterId = 1, detailInfo="bbbb"}
        }};

    var update = mapper.Map<Master, MasterDTO>(original1);
```

and the original value are :

```
original1: {Test.Program.Master}
  details [Icollection]: Count = 2
   [0]: {Test.Program.Detail}
     detailInfo [string]: "aaaa"
     id [int] : 11
     master [Master] : null
     masterId [int] : 1
   [1]: {Test.Program.Detail}
     detailInfo [string]: "bbbb"
     id [int] : 12
     master [Master] : null
     masterId [int] : 1
  id [int] : 1
  masterInfo [string]: "xxxx"
```

and the update/result value are :

```
update: {Test.Program.MasterDTO}
  details [Icollection]: Count = 0
  id [int] : 1
  masterInfo [string]: "xxxx"
```

Need your advice. Thanks  - Jigu

Comment: You need a `MapFrom` because the collections have no setter. Or a private setter if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `ForMember` method like this to map child property

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Master, MasterDTO>().ForMember(a => a.details, map => map.MapFrom(src => src.details));
    cfg.CreateMap<Detail, DetailDTO>();
});
```